# JSON Web Tokens vs session cookies

Tags: nodejs

¿Cual de los dos enfoques para el manejo de sesiones es mejor? En algunos casos afirman que el uso de los **JWT** es mejor, por la escalabilidad tanto horizontal como vertical y que mejora el rendimiento del servidor en caso de que el numero de usuarios sea grande. Por otra parte, otros afirman que el enfoque con **cookie-session** es mejor.
Quiero realizar un proyecto usando node-js, me gustaría saber cual de los enfoques es mejor y ¿por qué?

Comment: ¿Que problema has encontrado con uno u otro? Debería cambiar tu pregunta y acotar más le problema que te has encontrado. Así tal cual está da lugar a respuestas, de tenerlas, basadas en opiniones. Es uno de lo motivos de cierre.

Comment: hasta ahora he comenzado con el desarrollo de mi proyecto con node, y ahora voy a realizar la parte de inicio de sesión, pero estaba buscando cual de los dos enfoques es mejor para implementarlo - @OscarR

Comment: Una `cookie-session` recomendado para hacer uso de recursos del cliente como del servidor, es decir la cookie se almacena en el navegador del cliente mientras que la session se almacena en tu base de datos que le indiques, la finalidad de esto es que el usuario autenticado sea autenticado en base a la session guarda en la base de datos. A esto añadele que las `cookies` se las pueden acceder desde la mismo dominio, mientras si trabajas con `JWT` los puedes utilizar desde diferentes dominios si la almacenas en localstorage o en otros. recuerda que para `cookie-session` la percistencia de datos l